# Definition of a Boundary Action

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading [An Intrinsic Characterization of $C^*$-Simplicity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.01870.pdf) by Matthew Kennedy and have a question about the definition of a boundary action. On page 4, he says that the definition of a boundary action is given in section 2.3. I've read through section 2.3 several times but I don't see a definition of boundary action. Am I going crazy? If someone can spot it, would you please point it out? If section 2.3 does not in fact have the definition, would someone please kindly provide the definition of boundary action as used by the author (I can't suss out the meaning).

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of this text is that a $G$-space $X$ is called a $G$-boundary if (...definition that follows...). When $X$ is a $G$-boundary, the action of $G$ on $X$ should be called a boundary action. I don't see any other plausible interpretation of this text.

Hope that helps,